# SharePoint online unlicensed users

Tags: sharepoint-online, licence

I recently found that users can access SharePoint online without any license assigned once their permissions are added in SharePoint online.

Is there any limitations if users within organisation access SharePoint online without license ?

*It does not come under breaching of license agreement as Microsoft itself is giving the option of creating user Licensed or Unlicensed user.*

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking the terms of service/license agreement if you let unlicensed those users use SPO.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I am trying to find the answer how we are breaking as Microsoft itself gives the option to create user as licensed or unlicensed ?

Comment: To use a particular licensed feature, such as SPO, the user needs to have a license assigned. It's just that SPO doesn't perform license checks/enforcement, unlike some other services.

Comment: I agree that there are some features not available to unlicensed user but why SPO doesn't perform license checks ? Is this something that Microsoft itself providing an advantage to use SPO

Answer (score 1):

This is the current behavior that users without SharePoint Online license still can access SharePoint online.

Unfortunately no official article mentions about this and what doesn't work when users don't have the license.

In my opinion, unlicensed users cannot use some services in the SharePoint online, such as PowerApps、Flow etc.